# Does Website slows the WiFi connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, r

I have a WiFi connection and 8 people are sharing.

The 8th person suddenly made his own "website" similar to YouTube sharing videos, our countries TV stations, movie channels, movies, songs, etc. Our internet connection became so slow and cannot even open photos from FB anymore.

Before I shared the WiFi with this person, our connection was fast and I was downloading movies before this person arrived.  Now I can't even play a YouTube video without waiting for 30 mins to download. FB doesn't even browse fast anymore.

FYI, I have already upgraded.
Could you advise if this is the reason why my internet has become so slow?

Comment: Most probably, yes, this is the reason. To prove it, disconnect him from your network and see if your normal browsing speed is restored. You can then have good reason to ask the user to stop the service and pay for proper hosting in data centres who can cater for such bandwidth requirements.

Comment: What do you mean he made his own website? Where is he hosting it? Inside your LAN?

Answer (score 1):

Most consumer broadband connections are either ADSL or VDSL.  Both these technologies are asymetric.  This means that the speed from your router out to the Internet is much slower than the speed from the Internet back to your router.

When you surf the Internet (eg FB) you will send a small request to the webserver, which then return much more information in the form of text, images, videos etc.

When you check email, you will send a small outbound request and the server will reply with all your outstanding mail.

The pattern here is that you generally send much less than you receive.  Your broadband is designed around this principle and has slower upload than download speed.

When your colleague starts hosting on the same Internet connection, your *outbound* traffic now increases as everyone who navigates to your colleague's site will be requesting traffic, which can only be transferred to the Internet and onwards to their browsers via your relatively slow outbound link.  This means that there won't be much capacity left on the outbound route for you and your other colleagues' relatively small requests.  They basically get swamped by the webserver traffic.  The upshot is that although the downstream link is still under utilised, the remote server (FB in your example) doesn't get the request in the first place, so obviously will not respond.  To you it seems that FB is slow, whereas in reality, FB is fine and the problem is that you cannot request pages from FB.

Answer (score 0):

This could very well be the reason. If anyone is uploading a lot of data, the downloads are also affected.

This is because downloads over TCP/IP need to send receive confirmations back, and these 'have difficulty' going out to the server again.

You probably have an asymmetric connection where the max upload speed is much lower than the max download speed.
The provider does this because generally people download more than they upload, but it could also be to *prevent* you from uploading a lot. You should check that running a webserver is not a violation of the terms of service of the provider.